# Как бороться с агрессивным кэшированием (appCache) firefox?

Tags: firefox, кэширование, кроссбраузерность

Вопрос касается технологии HTML5 Application Cache.

Есть сайт, полностью динамический, во время онлайна не должен кэшироваться.

Задача: на случай оффлайна сайта нужно отображать страницу-заглушку (FALLBACK) при посещении любой страницы, в том числе корневой. При этом, должна быть **одна** страница, на которой заглушка *не должна* отображаться, то есть всегда должна запрашиваться из сети, даже во время оффлайна.

Файл манифеста:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

NETWORK:
allways_online.html

FALLBACK:
/ /fallback.html
```

В хроме работает ожидаемым образом. Браузер Firefox отображает `fallback.html` даже на странице `allways_online.html`, предписания в секции "NETWORK" игнорирует. Страница `allways_online.html` не содержит подключения манифеста.

Как решить проблему для Firefox'а?

Answer (score 0):

Спецификация в какой-то момент [поменялась](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/dea2e9c97718df4c9017e43ba218018491092308): до этого изменения именно поведения Firefox было корректным для этого манифеста. В Firefox это [так и не исправили (и даже не планируют, надеясь отключить когда-нибудь эту функциональность вообще)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=841937).

Поэтому либо переходить на Service Workers (рекомендуемая замена AppCache), либо придумывать такую структуру манифеста, чтобы ваша always-online страничка имела префикс, не перечисленный в списке тех, для которых указан FALLBACK.